# How should we combine the div with link_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, link-to

My original intention was to display some text on the image. At the same time, when we click the images, the webpage will be redirected. 
And I use link_to function with div containing background image.
The code is like this:

```
 <%= link_to raw('<div style="background-image:url(<%= image_url  '1.jpg'%>);width:340px;"> This is a  test</div>'),index_by_dvp_domain_path %>
```

But the system tells me there is SyntaxError.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass link_to a block that contains the content you want to display.  So instead of going with the `link_to(display, url, options={})` you get `link_to(url, option={}, &block)` where you can do.

```
<%= link_to index_by_dvp_domain_path do %>
  <div style="background-image: url(<%= image_url '1.jpg'%>);width:340px;"> 
   This is a  test
  </div>
<% end %>
```

After you do this you can treat it like normal html.

As always, I'd recommend trying to move any style out into it's own separate stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it this is used following

```
<%= link_to index_by_dvp_domain_path do
      content_tag(:div, 'This is a  test',:style=>"background-image:url(#{image_url}  '1.jpg');width:340px;" )
    end
%>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:div, 'This is a  test',:style=>"background-image:url(#{image_url}  '1.jpg');width:340px;" ), index_by_dvp_domain_path  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try with

```
<%= link_to raw('<div style="background-image:url(#{image_url  '1.jpg'}%>);width:340px;"> This is a  test</div>'),index_by_dvp_domain_path %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using Link_to as below would be much more simpler even when you have a big block including multiple tags:

```
<%= link_to desired_path do %>
    <div class="linkable">
        <another div>
             ... some other tags
        </another div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

and I recommend you to use a different background color for mouse over events because it shows the viewer that it's a link!

In you .css file:

```
.linkable:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Im so surprised to see that no one came up with the regular way of doing it in Rails.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/images/1.jpg",:size => "340X340"),index_by_dvp_domain_path %>
```